# Custom an annotation view image

Tags: image, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I want to custom the image of my annotation view. I try this :

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    //

    var lati: CLLocationDegrees = location.coordinate.latitude
    var longi: CLLocationDegrees = location.coordinate.longitude
    var locCoord:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lati, longi)
    var point = MKPointAnnotation()
    point.coordinate = locCoord
    point.title = "Title"

    self.myMapView.addAnnotation(point)
    var anView:MKAnnotationView = mapView(self.myMapView, viewForAnnotation: point)

}

//{...}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if !(annotation is MKPointAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView.image = UIImage(named:"imageName")
        anView.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        anView.annotation = annotation
    }

    return anView
}
```

But I keep the famous Annotation pin from Apple and not my image named "imageName".

I know I have **not** to do a `MKPinAnnotationView` to custom it. So I just did a `MKAnnotationView`. An idea ?

Comment: It sounds like the map view's `delegate` is not set in which case the viewForAnnotation delegate method won't get called and so you get the default red pin.  Note that you should _not_ directly call viewForAnnotation yourself like you are doing in didUpdateLocations.  The map view will call that method automatically as long as its `delegate` is set.

Comment: Thanks. But What do you want to say with "map view's delegate" ? 
So i can replace this `var anView:MKAnnotationView = mapView(self.myMapView, viewForAnnotation: point)` by `var anView:MKAnnotationView`?

Comment: No, you don't create an annotation view there at all.  In storyboard, connect the map view's delegate outlet to the view controller or in code, in viewDidLoad, do `self.myMapView.delegate = self`.  Then, the map view will call the viewForAnnotation itself when you add an annotation.

Comment: Oh ok ! So my line is useless (cause I connect with the Storyboard). And what about the image so ?

Comment: @Anna  If i don't call it, I don't go in my func `mapView` so the line `anView.image = UIImage(named:"imageName")` is never compiled.

Comment: If the delegate is set, the map view should call the viewForAnnotation method (don't call it yourself).  Otherwise, code looks ok.  Instead of "never compiled", do you mean "never executed" (there's a difference)?  At the very top of the viewForAnnotation, add `println("viewForAnnotation: ann = \(annotation)")`, run the app and see what it says in the console.  You'll need to some debugging or post more code to find out why it's still not calling the method.  You can also put a breakpoint inside viewForAnnotation and step through the code and check variable values.

Comment: If I delete the call of the viewForAnnotation `var anView:MKAnnotationView = mapView(self.map, viewForAnnotation: myPetPin)`, my `func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!`is never executed ;) 
Do you have an idea why ?